# Hide navigation bar without delay in Android

Tags: java, android, uinavigationbar, fullscreen

I have a simple application which loads in the background an `ImageView`.

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/splashimage"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:src="@drawable/logo"
    android:visibility="gone"/>
```

I am trying to load the image in full screen mode, meaning no navigation bar and no app bar. I have been able to remove te `appbar` from the very first moment that I run the application by setting the following flag:

```
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Nevertheless, when I try to do the same with the navigation bar at the bottom of the application, there is some delay before getting removed. Therefore, the behaviour is a bit weird. What it happens is that first the `navigation bar` is shown, next it is hidden and shows a white `background`, and only after a second the image fills the gap. I attach a photo to try to reproduce the situation as clear as possible.

My question is, how could I show the image covering that space from the beginning rather than following the 3 steps behaviour mentioned below?

To hide the navigation bar this code is used;

```
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN |
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION |
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
```

[image]

Comment: Do you follow this? https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive#EnableFullscreen ? If so I don't see a 'smoother' way to achieve what you want.

Comment: Worked like charm buddy, just needed to write different values :) Thanks

Comment: Maybe answer your question yourself what exactly you changed in your code. This way others can learn as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After following Bruno s comment I have updated my code and solve the error:

```
 getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE
            // Set the content to appear under the system bars so that the
            // content doesn't resize when the system bars hide and show.
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            // Hide the nav bar and status bar
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
```

Note that I did not want to remove completely the `appbar`. Therefore I did not include the following line `| View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);` at the end.

**Update**

Note that if you want your layout to appear under the `appbar` and not under it, this line needs to be removed

```
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me without fail for fragments to which I navigated, I put this code in MainActivity

```
        navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment_activity_main);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, appBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(binding.navView, navController);

        navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener(new NavController.OnDestinationChangedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDestinationChanged(@NonNull NavController navController,
                                             @NonNull NavDestination navDestination,
                                             @Nullable Bundle bundle) {
                BottomNavigationView navBar = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
                if(navDestination.getId() == R.id.navigation_librarySlideShowFragment ||
                        navDestination.getId() == R.id.navigation_settings ||
                        navDestination.getId() == R.id.wifiSettingsFragment ||
                        navDestination.getId() == R.id.playbackFragment) {
                    navBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                } else {
                    navBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }
```